# Where to put user logged in vs user logged out logic?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I know I'm doing this wrong.

When my app opens, I need to tell whether the user is logged in or logged out (and depending on that, open a different view controller).

My solution is in this image below.

[image]

I know this is wrong (it's just an empty View Controller for one function) but I don't know where else I could put this logic.

On top of this, I also need to know whether the user is a paid customer or a free customer (each gets a different home page).
How do I check this too without building an entire new View Controller just for that purpose?

**Edit**

One comment asked me to paste my code, so here it is:
`
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CheckIfLoggedInViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            // User is signed in. Show home screen
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoggedIn", sender: self)
        } else {
            // No User is signed in. Show user the login screen
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoggedOut", sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Please copy your code and paste it here and format it as code.

Comment: Woops... Is that why all the dislikes on this question?

Comment: Probably, I didn't down vote, but questions with code in pictures are hard to replicate, you can't just copy the picture and paste it in your own software to make it work. ;p

Comment: I pasted the code :) Still new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Good question as a new user. But as this is the asynchronous task so you should save the user login state in `UserDefaults` and check direct from this. Use `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design this white screen same like launch screen. It is the general  solution of this problem. When you done all your stuff (call apis, validation.. whatsoever) then navigate user to the required screen.

If your tasks are long then you can add some animations here, just like uber does. If you do not want any animation then make sure there is activity loader otherwise user assumes device is hanged due to your app.

> How do I check this too without building an entire new View Controller just for that purpose?

When you app loaded in memory `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called. If only you need to navigate user to either login or logout screen with condition then you can add code here.

But in this delegate, API call is not recommended.